# Уменьшить размер исполняемого файла rust

Tags: компиляция, rust

Хочу уменьшить размер исполняемого файла до минимума, вот код:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![feature(alloc_system)]
extern crate alloc_system;

fn main() {
    use std::net::TcpStream;

    let stream = TcpStream::connect("216.58.209.174:80")
                        .expect("Couldn't connect to the server...");
    stream.set_ttl(100).expect("set_ttl call failed");
    assert_eq!(stream.ttl().unwrap_or(0), 100);
}
```

Компилирую следующим образом: `rustc f.rs -C lto -C panic=abort -C opt-level=s`

Выдает:

> error[E0463]: can't find crate for `alloc_system`

В чем проблема я так и не понимаю, сборка нужна без `cargo`, а через `rustc` для добавления опций сборки компилятору.

Comment: Что мешает добаить опции сборки компилятору через cargo?

Comment: @andreymal пытался и через cargo [package.dev], но всё равно пишет что не найден крейт `alloc_system` + `can't perform LTO when compiling incrementally`

Comment: Точно не уверен, но кажется у вас устаревший код, поглядите куда-нибудь сюда https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/global-allocators.html

Comment: @andreymal хм, похоже что да, спасибо!